# How to execute the statement after sigwait

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, pthreads, signals

I am trying to learn about signals. I have written a small piece of code using sigwait and pthread_kill. The statement after sigwait is not getting executed even if I have issued the signal using pthread_kill. I am getting output as "Before
Real-time signal 0
"
Expected output:
"Before
 After"

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void *fun(void *arg)
{
    sigset_t set;
    int signal;
    sigemptyset(&set);
    sigaddset(&set,SIGRTMIN);

    printf("Before\n");
    sigwait(&set,&signal);
    printf("After\n");
}
int main()
{
    pthread_t obj;
    int ret = pthread_create(&obj,NULL,fun,NULL);
    sleep(10);
    pthread_kill(obj,SIGRTMIN);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have two problems in your code:

1) The `SIGRTMIN` signal will kill the thread outright, before `sigwait()` is able to dequeue it. If you want to have `sigwait` actually *return*, you should install a signal handler for it:

```
void sigh(int s){}
void *fun(void *arg)
{
    struct sigaction sa;
    sa.sa_handler = sigh;
    sigemptyset(&sa.sa_mask);
    sa.sa_flags = 0;
    sigaction(SIGRTMIN, &sa, 0);
    ...
```

2) You may be returning from `main()` before the child thread has exited, which again may kill it before being able to print the "After". Call `pthread_join(obj, 0)` or at least add a `sleep(1)` after `pthread_kill`.

Comment: Using sigaction fixed the issue. Thanks